# Require a library with configuration in CoffeeScript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, couchdb, couchdb-nano

I'd like to use CoffeeScript with Nano.js, a minimalistic CouchDB module. In JavaScript, the requirements are:

```
var nano = require('nano')('http://127.0.0.1:5984');
```

However, there is no documentation on how to write this in CoffeeScript?

```
nano = require 'nano', 'http://127.0.0.1:5984'
```

Results in:

```
nano = require('nano', 'http://127.0.0.1:5984');
```

Which doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are calling a function which calls a function, doing what you tried is ambiguous.  Parentheses are required in CoffeeScript to resolve ambiguity.  Have you tried this:

```
nano = require('nano')('http://127.0.0.1:5984')
```

Or, if you really want to go without parens, you could do this:

```
nano = require 'nano'
nano = nano 'http://127.0.0.1:5984'
```

Or just

```
nano = require('nano') 'http://127.0.0.1:5984'
```